# How to modify JSON to custom structure

Tags: c#, json, reactjs, i18next

Im trying to change my JSON that is read from a dataTable

> [{"englishText":"dog","languageText":"hund"},
>     {"englishText":"cat","languageText":"katt"},
>     {"englishText":"house","languageText":"hus"}]

to look like this

> {
>    "dog": "hund",
>    "cat" : "katt",
>     "house" : "hus"
>   }

so that i can use it with i18n in React

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Its har to know were to start so i haven't tried much. I made the first JSON with Newtonsoft.json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(table) in c#

Comment: Where these JSON data coming from ?

Comment: JSON data was generated from (Nwetonsoft.json) JsonConvert.SerializeObject(table) in c# where table is an sql Datatable

Comment: @untz123 why are you doing so? Why just don't select a values from table?

Comment: That would maybe be a better solution for next time. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) as follows:

```js
const source = [{"englishText":"dog","languageText":"hund"}, {"englishText":"cat","languageText":"katt"}, {"englishText":"house","languageText":"hus"}]

const target = source.reduce((obj, o) => {
  obj[o.englishText] = o.languageText;
  return obj;
}, {});

console.log(target);
```

Comment: Glad I could help you start with this.